# Using dynamic table name on postgresql Trigger

Tags: postgresql

i have the following trigger that i would like to use in multiple tables. So, how i could make it work  instead having one trigger for each table?

```
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        UPDATE test_table set rel_label = (select SUBSTR(release, 1, 5)) where uid=OLD.uid;
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        UPDATE test_table  set rel_label = (select SUBSTR(release, 1, 5)) where uid=OLD.uid;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL; -- result ignored since is an AFTER TRIGGER
END;
```

regards.

Comment: So you want to change the `test_table` name for each trigger?

Comment: The oposite. i would like to have the trigger working for any table without having the specify the table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out a straight solution.

```
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                NEW.rel_label = (select SUBSTR(NEW.release, 1, 5));
                RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                NEW.rel_label = (select SUBSTR(NEW.release, 1, 5));
                RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
            RETURN NULL;

END;
```

Comment: That was what my question was aiming at ;)

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation on the [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) command.